# Error when opening the product page.I havent changes the code level

Tags: magento-2.1, product, php, product-attribute

1 exception(s):

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php
>   on line 88

http://107.22.132.126/singing-bowl-20.html[image]

Comment: You chnage somthing in this file  /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php this error is showing when you try to echo an array

Answer (score 0):

Try to run from magento root the following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: nothing change after upgrading the magento again same error occur

Comment: seems works fine now!